# Serialize JSON to JSON Array (Nested JSON) for POST Request C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

### This is what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to serialize my model into a JSON for post request to insert records

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "employee_num": "7812345",
            "code": "333",
            "startdate": "2020-10-03"
        },
        {
            "employee_num": "2345789",
            "code": "444",
            "startdate": "2020-10-03"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm stuck with this

```
{
     "employee_num": "7812345",
     "code": "333",
     "startdate": "2020-10-03"
},
{
     "employee_num": "2345789",
     "code": "444",
     "startdate": "2020-10-03"
}
```

Here is my code

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
WriteIndented = false
};
var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model, options);
```

Newbie here

Comment: Can you post the model/class for Model.

Comment: What *you are stuck with* isn't valid JSON. You have two objects not in a collection. Try serializing `new {Data = model}`

Comment: Welcome to SO Ken! 2 Questions: Is the the `Data` element/level necessary? Do you have access to the classes used by the api you are `POST`ing to?

Comment: @ShaiCohen The data element is necessary because I'm using a middle ware to process/handle the API. There's no other way to submit 1 post request for the middle ware to capture number of data.

Comment: @Jawad It's like this 
`class Model
 {
public string employee_num { get; set; }
public string code { get; set; }
public string startdate{ get; set; }
}`

Then I used List to add data
`public List<Model> model= new List<Model>();
Model.Add(new Model
{
employee_num = "1",
code = "1",
startdate = "1"
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the Json Conerter from newtonsoft and got it the format you want.

```
Test t = new Test("Max", "Musterallee", "Mustermann@Muster.de");
Test t1 = new Test("Max2", "Musterallee2", "Mustermann2@Muster.de");

Test2 t2 = new Test2();
t2.addUser(t);
t2.addUser(t1);
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t2);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Test:

```
class Test
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string adress { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public Test(string name, string adress, string email)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.adress = adress;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Test2:

```
class Test2
{
    public List<Test> Data;
    public Test2()
    {
        Data = new List<Test>();
    }

    public void addUser (Test t1)
    {
        Data.Add(t1);
    }
}
```

And the output looked like this:

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      "name": "Max",
      "adress": "Musterallee",
      "email": "Mustermann@Muster.de"
    },
    {
      "name": "Max2",
      "adress": "Musterallee2",
      "email": "Mustermann2@Muster.de"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Is there a way to load multiple data without creating new instance of the model? I used this way of adding the data:

public List<Model> model= new List<Model>();

then adding new data in the list

Comment: Adding data like this

model.Add(new Model
            {
                employee_num = "7812345",
code = "444",
startdate = "2020-01-01"
            });

Answer (score 0):

Well, Technically, your `json` suggests you should have a model like this:

```
public partial class SomeClass // You can choose some better class names.
{
    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public List<Datum> Data { get; set; }
    public SomeClass()
    {
        Data = new List<Datum>();
    }

}

public partial class Datum
{
    [JsonProperty("employee_num")]
    public string EmployeeNum { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("startdate")]
    public string Startdate { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how it is going to be populated:

```
var someClassObj = new SomeClass();

var datum = new Datum
{
    EmployeeNum = "123",
    Code = "321",
    StartDate = "2003-03-03"
};
someClassObj.Data.Add(datum);
// You can add more objects in it as per your need.
```

And then to serialize this to a `json` you should do:

```
var json = JsonConvert.Serialize(someClassObj);
```

The output will be this:

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "employee_num": "123",
            "code": "321",
            "startdate": "2003-03-03"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to have difference instance of the model everytime I add a new data? Thank you for the solution by the way. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I got it now guys. Instead of creating new instance for the new record, I just reuse the existing then change the values and add again to the List object. Thank you for the time. Really appreciate it.